# Отменить padding родителя

Tags: javascript, css, padding

Как отменить padding родителя для img, но оставить его для текста, разметить тегами текст невозможно.  Что можно сделать с img чтобы он не наследовал родительский стиль? Подойдет любой метод js, css

```
<div padding:20px>
<img src="">
текст
текст 
<img src="">
текст 
текст 
</div>
```

Comment: Что это у вас за псевдокод `<div padding:20px>`?

Comment: img{margin: -20px} не помогло, пробовал

Comment: Вам сначала нужно сюда [Введение в html](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_HTML)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку ага

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сместить изображение, сделав его относительно позиционированным и указанть "margin: -20px";

Это то, что Вам нужно было?

```
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/voEmvg
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/982/536/354">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A expedita maxime distinctio quod optio quia tempora ea sit libero magni.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, nam?</p>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/982/536/354">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A expedita maxime distinctio quod optio quia tempora ea sit libero magni.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, nam?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Так сработало, Картинка заполняет всю ширину родителя .img{
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    max-width: -webkit-fill-available !important;
}